# exception for app in release mode, not in debug mode

Tags: uitableview, swift

I'm having an exception in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and i'm not quite sure why. I'm showing the user a list of possibilities they can select from, the `UITableView` is populated based on values stored in Core Data. The currently selected item has a `Checkmark` indicator. My method is below:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let value = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CoreDataObject
    currentSelected = value.id as Int

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In development mode it's fine, but in production and testflight it crashes in this method. The crash log is below:

```
Crashed Thread 0 :
0   CoreFoundation  0x25f41a7d  _CFRetain + 165
1   UIKit   0x29619d67  -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 919
2   UIKit   0x296cb9df  -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 195
3   UIKit   0x2957da25  _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 309
4   UIKit   0x294f982b  _afterCACommitHandler + 459
5   CoreFoundation  0x26007d95  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 21
6   CoreFoundation  0x26005453  __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 279
7   CoreFoundation  0x2600585b  __CFRunLoopRun + 915
8   CoreFoundation  0x25f533c1  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
9   CoreFoundation  0x25f531d3  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
10  GraphicsServices    0x2d3510a9  GSEventRunModal + 137
11  UIKit   0x29562fa1  UIApplicationMain + 1441
```

Is there anything i'm missing here? Why is this method crashing? I'm simply storing the currently selected ID and then reloading data so that it can show a checkmark after the reload. Is there something i'm missing here? It should be as simple as just getting the new id and then reloading the data.

The `CoreDataObject` that i'm using is from `Objective-C` and the `id` field is an `NSNumber`.

I tried other solutions below:

[Crash when calling selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057090/crash-when-calling-selectrowatindexpathanimatedscrollposition)

[iphone app crash at -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981466/iphone-app-crash-at-uitableview-selectrowatindexpathanimatedscrollposition)

[iOS - didSelectRowAtIndexPath causes crash in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612330/ios-didselectrowatindexpath-causes-crash-in-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else has this issue. `currentSelected` was a global variable declared as `Int` and the `value` object has an `id` field thats `NSNumber. I changed it to the below and it works:

```
self.currentSelected = value.id.integerValue
```